# get utc time from time of a zone moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, momentjs

It's 07.00 AM here in `Asia/Kolkata`. I'm sightly confusing to calculate time using MomentJS.

Can anyone tell me please how to calculate time for `America/Los_Angeles` and, how to get UTC time according to question?

Answer (score 1):

To get American / Los Angeles, you'd run:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

To get UTC, you'd run:

```
moment().tz("UTC").format();
```

Comment: sorry but please explain more  by using given data also  you didn't use my current timezone anywhere. is it not useful ?

Comment: America/Los_Angeles and UTC are time zones relative to other time zones.  There is no need to reference a specific time zone retrieve to the others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a moment object with Asia/Kolkata timezone and then convert it to America/Los_Angeles timezone.

Convert Date/Time between timezones

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```